# XSLT delete elements in the XML

Tags: xslt-1.0

Can someone explain how I can transform Input XML to Output XML shown below using XSLT.
I need to delete the 'RElement' in the XML that doesn't have 'Type' element with Value 'Account' in its descendant child elements. 
    'RElement' is recursive.

Input XML-

```
<RElement>
<Type>Group</Type>
<RElement>
<Type>Group</Type>
<RElement>
  <Type>Account</Type>
</RElement>
</RElement>
<RElement>
<Type>Group</Type>
<RElement>
  <Type>Group</Type>
  <RElement>
    <Type>Group</Type>
  </RElement>
 </RElement>
 </RElement>
 </RElement>
```

Output XML-

```
<RElement>
 <Type>Group</Type>
<RElement>
 <Type>Group</Type>
<RElement>
  <Type>Account</Type>
</RElement>
</RElement>
</RElement>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please edit the question and show your current XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="RElement[not(.//Type[text() = 'Account'])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically it's Identity transform with an empty template for RElement elements that doesn't have 'Type' element with Value 'Account' in its descendant child elements.

**Edited** to add Ian Robert's empty template, which is better:

```
<xsl:template match="RElement[not(.//Type = 'Account')]" />
```

Comment: Or simpler, `<xsl:template match="RElement[not(.//Type = 'Account')]" />` - you don't need `text()` in this situation because what you care about is the complete string value of the `Type` element, not the individual text node(s) within it.